# Making a "leave textbox" event

Tags: c#

How can I make an event so when I leave a text box it enables a certain button? I'm pretty sure I need to somehow use the focus control but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `Leave` event of the control, see some examples [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I leave the textbox and the button still remains disabled (by default). And I can't find the Leave event in the list of button events. Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: @Boyer The leave event is in the list of the textbox events. You cannot really "leave" a button. :)

Comment: Uh, my bad, that's what I meant, I can't find it in the textbox events. Sorry for the typo..

Comment: @Boyer That's strange, it should be there... [screenshot](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/images/csharp_2013/events/textbox_leave.gif)

Comment: The list has the following : DataBinding, Disposed, Init, Load, PreRender, TextChanged, Unload.

Answer (score -1):

use this syntax textbox1_TextChanged